# How to sort a color array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an made of colors. What I am trying to do is to sort the array from lowest in RGB colors to highest in RGB colors. I tried using `Arrays.sort()` but its not a comparable that `Arrays.sort()` can handle. How can I do this?

```
System.out.println("anchors unsorted: " + Arrays.toString(allAnchorColors));
Arrays.sort(allAnchorColors);
System.out.print("anchors sorted: " + Arrays.toString(allAnchorColors));
```

output:

```
anchors unsorted: [java.awt.Color[r=255,g=186,b=34], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=14,b=20], java.awt.Color[r=2,g=255,b=168], java.awt.Color[r=242,g=231,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=26,b=28], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=65,b=255]]
```

Comment: I think you need to start by asking yourself, how you would like them to be sorted, because you have an object with at least 3 primary properties

Comment: I stated that in my question @MadProgrammer . Lowest RGB values to highest RGB values. So from (0,0,0) to (255,255,255)

Comment: It's not that easy, `255, 0, 0` goes where when compared to `0, 255, 0`

Comment: ie is red more important than green or blue for sorting?

Comment: yes it is I would say @Jason

Comment: Then you could convert the RGB values into R*256*256+G*256+B and have an integer value on which to sort. You would then just need a custom  compare operator.

Comment: This is what I got after sorting, is this acceptable?java.awt.Color[r=0,g=65,b=255]
java.awt.Color[r=2,g=255,b=168]
java.awt.Color[r=242,g=231,b=255]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=14,b=20]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=186,b=34]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=26,b=28]

Comment: Sure that would be acceptable @DeeJay .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not an easy one to answer directly because `Color` is made up of at least three primary properties (not including alpha ;)), but indirectly, you need to supply a custom `Comparator` which can sort the colors based on your requirements, for example.

This basically makes use of the `getRGB` method which converts the value into a packed `int` value, making the comparison simpler

```
Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};
for (Color color: colors) {
    System.out.println(color.getRGB() + "; " + color);
}

Arrays.sort(colors, new Comparator<Color>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Color o1, Color o2) {
        return o1.getRGB() - o2.getRGB();
    }
});
System.out.println("After");
for (Color color: colors) {
    System.out.println(color.getRGB() + "; " + color);
}
```

Which prints out...

```
-65536; java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
-16711936; java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]
-16776961; java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]
-16777216; java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
-1; java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
After
-16777216; java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
-16776961; java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]
-16711936; java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0]
-65536; java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
-1; java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
```

This "kind of" meets your requirements, in the fact that `BLACK` is before `WHITE` :P

However, the answer remains the same, you need to supply a custom `Comparator` which generates the required result when comparing two values based on your algorithm for sorting

> I am looking at this but am a little confused because when I implemented what you had here I got a bunch of other colors which I didn't have before

Based on the available information you've been able to provide me, the sort algorithm isn't adding any new values...

```
Color[] allAnchorColors = {
    new Color(255, 200, 63),
    new Color(255, 8, 12),
    new Color(0, 255, 148),
    new Color(223, 214, 255),
    new Color(255, 19, 19),
    new Color(0, 76, 255),
};
System.out.println("anchors.length = " + allAnchorColors.length);
System.out.println("anchors unsorted: " + Arrays.toString(allAnchorColors));
Arrays.sort(allAnchorColors, new Comparator<Color>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Color o1, Color o2) {
        return o1.getRGB() - o2.getRGB();
    }
});
System.out.println("anchors.length = " + allAnchorColors.length);
System.out.print("anchors sorted: " + Arrays.toString(allAnchorColors));
```

Which outputs...

```
anchors.length = 6
anchors unsorted: [java.awt.Color[r=255,g=200,b=63], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=8,b=12], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=148], java.awt.Color[r=223,g=214,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=19,b=19], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=76,b=255]]
anchors.length = 6
anchors sorted: [java.awt.Color[r=0,g=76,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=148], java.awt.Color[r=223,g=214,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=8,b=12], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=19,b=19], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=200,b=63]]BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

which means, there is something in you code which you're not showing us that's causing the issue

Comment: I am looking at this but am a little confused because when I implemented what you had here I got a bunch of other colors which I didn't have before.

Comment: You'd have to provide an example, based on my example, there were 5 colors before and after

Comment: This is what I did. `System.out.println("anchors unsorted: " + Arrays.toString(allAnchorColors));
 
  Arrays.sort(allAnchorColors, new Comparator<Color>() {
   @Override
   public int compare (Color o1 , Color o2) {
    return o1.getRGB() - o2.getRGB();
   }
  });
  
  System.out.print("anchors sorted: " + Arrays.toString(allAnchorColors));`

Comment: And what's `allAnchorColors` contain?

Comment: it contains the colors I am trying to sort.

Comment: Show me the list of colors

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue based on the information you've provided, see update, it's all based on the information you've provided so far

Comment: Sorry it is working fine I had two things being printed on the same line for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to forest, watch out for the trees ;)

Comment: Your solution works fine I will accept it :) thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got the result, Simply sorting them as String values,

```
        String[] arr = {"java.awt.Color[r=255,g=186,b=34]", "java.awt.Color[r=255,g=14,b=20]", "java.awt.Color[r=2,g=255,b=168]", "java.awt.Color[r=242,g=231,b=255]","java.awt.Color[r=255,g=26,b=28]","java.awt.Color[r=0,g=65,b=255]"};
        java.util.Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (String string : arr) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
```

Edit 1:

```
for (Color color : colorArray) {
    String strColorValue = String.valueOf( color );
    //Make a new arraylist and append strColorValue to it.
    //Sort the list as above.
}
```

Comment: how would I take my color array and get the values the array into a string like you have here?

Comment: Your implementation works too. However, It is more reliant on the ordering of strings and not exactly the value represented by the colors

Comment: this is a valid solution too. I upvoted it. It gives me the same result as the other answer :) thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the only way to solve the problem but it's pehaps the most direct.
Transform each color into HSV space and then order them by Hue (H). See [this page](https://programmingdesignsystems.com/color/color-models-and-color-spaces/index.html) for an explanation and demonstration. An algorithm to go from RGB to HSV is given on [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556341/rgb-to-hsv-color-conversion-algorithm). Something like this

```
public class RGBtoHSV {
  float r;
  float g;
  float b;
  public RGBtoHSV(int red, int green, int blue) {
    //Scale to float from 8 bit RGB values
    r = red/255;
    g = green/255;
    b = blue/255;
  }
  public int[] getHSV() {
    float cmax = Math.max(r, Math.max(g, b));
    float cmin = Math.min(r, Math.min(g, b));
    float deltaC = cmax - cmin;
    float h;
    if (cmax==r) {
        h = (((g-b)/deltaC)%6)*60;
    } else if (cmax==g) {
        h = (((b-r)/deltaC) + 2)*60;
    } else {
      h = (((r-g)/deltaC) + 4)*60;
    }
    float s = 0;
    if (cmax!=0) {
      s = deltaC/cmax;
    }
    int[] returnValue = new int[3];
    // re-scale
    returnValue[0] = (int) h/255;
    returnValue[1] = (int) s/255;
    returnValue[2] = (int) cmax/255;
    return returnValue;
}
```

With the integer h value, choose a starting point h value (as with the cheese wedge in the first link). Then increment (or decrement) mod 256 to get them in order.